# Foward empty arguments to GNU parallel does not work?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have the following

```sh
function doit() { echo "'$1', '$2', '$3'"; }
export -f doit
args=("a" "") # Empty argument
echo -e "1\n2" | parallel -k "doit" "${args[@]}" {}
```

Which does not forward the empty argument:

```
'a', '1', ''
'a', '2', ''
```

instead it should be

```
'a', '', '1'
'a', '', '2'
```

Why does parallel do this and how to fix it?

Comment: these args come from '$@'. So i dont want to modify them...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parallel` passed strings to `bash -c` - they are interpreted according to shell rules, empty arguments are just concatenated and subject to word splitting expansion.

If you want to preserve arguments, quote them. Either `"$(printf "%q " "${args[@]}")"` manually or just `parallel -q` or `parallel --quote`.